# Selenium IDE scripts stopped working - failing to find element with ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have been using Selenium IDE (with Chrome and Firefox) with no issue until yesterday. All of a sudden, all of the scripts I have with a particular web site - 22 tests in all - are failing. They are failing on the same thing, and in both Chrome and Firefox. They are failing to match an element by its id.

So, let me just say this is not an obscure id, nor one that changes. The id is `username`. It is present on the page, but Selenium fails to find it.

Even weirder, if I set it to Record, the new command that I record uses the exact same id (target: id=username). When I try playback again ... NOPE. Element doesn't exist. It definitely does, numb-nuts, you literally just found it on the page seconds ago!

Any explanation as to what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried an alternative identifier or can you share the url for anyone else to verify things like versions?

Comment: It's not publicly available, unfortunately. Also it's failing on *all* ids - even ones that I have just recorded. Same for Firefox. Strangely, the scripts are all working perfectly on Edge. So who knows what's going on?